# Why is one identifier in a CREATE TABLE double-quoted, but not the others?

Tags: sql, postgresql, identifier, ddl

I set the table

```
CREATE TABLE author (
  id serial NOT NULL,
  name character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  orcid character varying(128) NOT NULL,
  "position" integer NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT author_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id )
);
```

Why does the `"position"` name contain `""`?
How can I remove `""` from `position`?

Comment: If you want to get rid of the double quotes, you must choose a different column name, one that is not a reserved word.

Answer (score 1):

[According to the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html), `position` is

> non-reserved (cannot be function or type)

It's a reserved word in standard SQL. What you see is probably the output of `pgAdmin` or some other client that double-quoting all reserved words in SQL standard when used as identifiers.

This statement is syntactically correct:

```
SELECT position FROM author LIMIT 1;
```

You *can* always double-quote identifiers (thereby preserving mixed-case spelling). This works, too:

```
SELECT "position" FROM author LIMIT 1;
```

But double quotes are required here:

```
SELECT "where" FROM author LIMIT 1;
SELECT "CaMeL" FROM author LIMIT 1;
SELECT "a-b-c" FROM author LIMIT 1;
```