# Cannot set column names to numbers or symbols in postgresql / rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I need to add columns in my table tournament. My columns all correspond to a specific ranking and are of boolean type. 
My rankings name in real life look like : 40, 30/5, 30/4, 30/3 ect ect
But I dont think I can writte a migration like this in rails :

```
class AddRankingsToTournaments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change 
    add_column :tournaments, :40, :boolean
    add_column :tournaments, :30/5, :boolean
    add_column :tournaments, :30/3, :boolean
  end
end
```

This would not be valid column names in rails and postgresql right ? 
What would be my best shot to rename my column names to something correct and still easy to indentify ?

Comment: Tricky one. How would you use this columns? Are planning on querying them?

Comment: What about changing them to `forty` or using aliases in Rails model?

Comment: Not sure about Ruby, but you need to double-quote otherwise illegal identifiers in Postgres. Like `"30/5"`. Not that it would be a good idea to use such names to begin with - very error prone. Details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13004915/939860, http://stackoverflow.com/a/20880247/939860

Comment: @BroiSatse yep I need to query them at some point to check if ```@tournament.40``` is true or false for example
Yes I could change them to forty, thirtyfive... but I would lose the language & symbols specific to the business logic of my app !